# Loop Issue Counting Year In PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have created a loop which will display date 2004 to 2014 in a formatted way. But the problem is, it is showing 204 instead of 2004 and continue this till 209.. So, how to show those year in formatted way, like 2004,2005,2006 etc.
Here is the code i have created, tell me where to fix:

```
<?php
    $yr = 4;
    while ($yr <= 14) {
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Jan 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Feb 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Mar 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Apr 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x May 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Jun 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Jul 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Aug 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Sep 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Oct 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Nov 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Dec 20$yr<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $yr++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason your going through such a long process for something so simple? There are many PHP functions that can help you to get your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you can try this. Though its not a standard way:

```
<?php
$yar = 4;
while ($yar <= 9) {
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Jan 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Feb 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Mar 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Apr 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax May 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Jun 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Jul 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Aug 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Sep 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Oct 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Nov 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $ax = 1;
    while ($ax <= 31) {
        echo "$ax Dec 200$yar <br>";
        $ax++;
    }
    $yar++;
}
$yr = 10;
while ($yr <= 14) {
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Jan 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Feb 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Mar 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Apr 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x May 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Jun 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Jul 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Aug 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Sep 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Oct 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Nov 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= 31) {
        echo "$x Dec 20$yr <br>";
        $x++;
    }
    $yr++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, though i know that its not a standard way,, but i was looking such codes! Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

All you need is one loop

```
$start = 2004;
$end = 2014;

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setDate($start, 1, 1);

echo "<pre>";
while ( $dateTime->format("Y") <= $end ) {
    echo $dateTime->format("d M Y"), PHP_EOL;
    $dateTime->modify("+1 day");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why go through such a long and odd process, when you can do something like this?

```
<?php
    $yearStart = 2004;
    $yearEnd = 2012;
    $unixTime = strtotime($yearStart . "-01-01 00:00:00");
    $endUnixTime = strtotime($yearEnd . "-12-31 23:59:59");
    while ($unixTime < $endUnixTime) {
        echo date("d M Y", $unixTime) . PHP_EOL;
        $unixTime = strtotime("+1 day", $unixTime);
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
01 Jan 2004
02 Jan 2004
03 Jan 2004
...
29 Dec 2012
30 Dec 2012
31 Dec 2012
```

This also has the added bonus of not showing "31 Feb 2008" etc., as that date doesn't even exist.

[Codepad example of the code (WARNING: long output!)](http://codepad.org/EvODIXwP)

Comment: Definitely easiest and shortest answer. Only "con" (Not much as a Con IMO) is it depends on `date()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering with example +1 :)

Comment: can u tell me how to use `str_replace` in this code instead of `echo`? Ama beginner in php coding :()

Comment: @MaxMuller What is that you want to `str_replace` with? You can use `ob_start` or simply `$buffer .= ` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why are you doing this by so many loops, use this instead of $yr and you will get the correct year printed:

```
 str_pad($yr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Best

Answer (score 2):

Easiest fix is to set $yr = 2004 and loop while $yr < 2014.  You are not padding your numbers with a leading zero, hence 204, 205, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't believe that.  If you set your variable to equal 2004, it will not print out 204.  Please check your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it also with a (Quite) different Structure:

```
<?php
    function displayDate($yr, $yrMax) {
        if ($yr > $yrMax) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            displayMonth($yr);
            $yr++;
            return displayDate($yr, $yrMax);
        }
    }
    function displayMonth($yr, $month = 1) {
        if ($month > 12) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            displayDay($yr, $month);
            return displayMonth($yr, $month+1);
        }
    }
    function displayDay($yr, $month, $day = 1, $dayMax = 31) {
            if ($day > $dayMax) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $displayMonth = getMonth($month);
                echo "$day $displayMonth $yr<br>";
                $day++;
                return displayDay($yr, $month, $day, $dayMax);
            }
    }
    function getMonth($month) {
        switch($month){
            case 1:
                return 'Jan';
            case 2:
                return 'Feb';
            case 3:
                return 'Mar';
            case 4:
                return 'Apr';
            case 5:
                return 'May';
            case 6:
                return 'Jun';
            case 7:
                return 'Jul';
            case 8:
                return 'Aug';
            case 9:
                return 'Sep';
            case 10:
                return 'Oct';
            case 11:
                return 'Nov';
            case 12:
                return 'Dec';
        }
    }

            //Here we call the structure build above.
    if (displayDate(2004, 2014)) {
        echo 'Done';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not standard, but you can add an if loop inside that while loop like this:

```
while($x <= 31) 
{
if ($yr>=10)
    {
       echo "$x Oct 20$yr<br>";
    }

else
    {
       echo "$x Oct 200$yr<br>";
    }

$x++;
}
```

While you'd wanna do something like this beats me though

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting `$yr` like that:

```
$yr = 4;
```

Try this:

```
$yr = sprintf('%02d', $yr);
echo "$x Jan 20$yr<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `str_pad` function ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)). In your case, it goes like this:

```
<?php 

    $yr = 4;
    while ($yr <= 14) {
        $x = 1;
        while ($x <= 31) {
            echo "$x Jan 20".str_pad($yr, 2, "0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br>";
            $x++;
        }
        $yr++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php):

```
echo $x.' Jan 20'.str_pad($yr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'<br>';
```

Is more appropriate to use the function [cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.cal-days-in-month.php)  of the variable *$x*:

```
<?php

    $yr = 4;
    while ($yr <= 14) {

        $year = '20'.str_pad($yr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {

            //number of days this month
            $daysCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year); 
            //catches the month spelled 
            $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
            $monthText = date('M', $timestamp);

            for($day = 1; $day <= $daysCount; $day++) {
                echo $day.' '.$monthText.' '.$year.'<br>';
            }
        }

        $yr++;
    }
?>
```