# PHP insert script for past amount of days

Tags: php, mysql

I need to populate a table with a row for each day over the past 5 years?

```
E.g
1. 04/11/2012
2. 03/11/2012
3. 02/11/2012
4. 01/11/2012
5. 31/10/2012
6. etc
```

This will just be a php script that I run once and inserts all of the records.

The reason for doing this is for performance testing my other code with enough data in the database.

Comment: what isn't working? [what have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Well I have no idea how to even start this. I dont have any code to show you apart from a INSERT

Comment: All I want to know is how to loop the set amount of days using `date()`

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13233933/1226894

Comment: Is that not what you want ?? just use `$dateTime->format("d/M/Y")` instead

Comment: @Baba yeah thats a perfect example which I can modify for my needs. Add this as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: The only issue i have is that mysql database takes `y-m-d` ?? why do you want  `04/11/2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the date-format you want:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($i." days"));
```

$i is the number of days past/ahead of this date. So if $i is -1 that means one day ago. I guess you could make a loop of it, decreasing/increasing $i.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$date = "2007-01-01";
while ($date != "2013-01-01") {

    //do your query... not going to do any escaping for brevity
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME (SomeDateColumn) VALUES ('$date')");
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) + 86400);
}
```

Comment: why? why....? why!!?!?????. use a `$days = 0; $days++` in PHP, then `insert into .... values (now() + interval $days)` in PHP. This is by far safer and handles DST changes

Comment: Is it?  What if the script starts at 23:59:59 and rolls over during the run?  Then a day will be skipped.  Obviously the hard-coded integer addition by me wasn't ideal but I'm not sure yours is either.  I would go with Undrium's solution whilst saving the current time before the loop and not referencing it in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = new DateTime(); // Now

$date = $new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P5Y')); // 5 years ago

while ($date->diff($now))->invert != 1)
{
    // insert $date into database
    // I'll leave that to you, as you were looking for a way to loop over dates

    $date->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```