# Compressing PHP code

Tags: php, optimization

I have created a PHP script but while using it in my hosting server it show fatal error, then i have discovered that i need to compress this PHP code to make my script working.. Here is the code, any one can compress this code with the same output, i am a beginner in coding so can't understand how to act this same output with minimized code and efforts so that server can easily execute this code. Thanks
The Code Need to be optimize:

```
$yar = 3;
while ($yar <= 9) {
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $jaan = "$ax Jan 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($jaan, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $feeb = "$ax Feb 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($feeb, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $maar = "$ax Mar 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($maar, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $appr = "$ax Apr 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($appr, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $maay = "$ax May 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($maay, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $juun = "$ax Jun 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($juun, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $juul = "$ax Jul 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($juul, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $auug = "$ax Aug 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($auug, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $seep = "$ax Sep 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($seep, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $occt = "$ax Oct 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($occt, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $noov = "$ax Nov 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($noov, " ", $result);
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    }
    $ax = 31;
    while ($ax > 0) {
        $deec = "$ax Dec 200$yar";
        $result = str_replace($deec, " ", $result);
    }
        $ax = $ax - 1;
    $yar++;
} //years start after 2010 to 2014
$yr = 10;
while ($yr <= 14) {
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $jan = "$x Jan 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($jan, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $feb = "$x Feb 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($feb, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $mar = "$x Mar 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($mar, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $apr = "$x Apr 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($apr, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $may = "$x May 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($may, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $jun = "$x Jun 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($jun, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $jul = "$x Jul 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($jul, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $aug = "$x Aug 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($aug, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $sep = "$x Sep 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($sep, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $oct = "$x Oct 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($oct, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $nov = "$x Nov 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($nov, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $x = 31;
    while ($x > 0) {
        $dec = "$x Dec 20$yr";
        $result = str_replace($dec, " ", $result);
        $x = $x - 1;
    }
    $yr++;
}
```

Comment: It's completely unclear why "compression" would help you. How did you discover this? Talking about optimization, what are you doing in your script anyways? A little explanation is likely to result in helpful suggestions of how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post the same code that I [posted in your previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233920/247893):

> Why go through such a long and odd process, when you can do something like this?

```
<?php
    $yearStart = 2004;
    $yearEnd = 2012;
    $unixTime = strtotime($yearStart . "-01-01 00:00:00");
    $endUnixTime = strtotime($yearEnd . "-12-31 23:59:59");
    while ($unixTime < $endUnixTime) {
        echo date("d M Y", $unixTime) . PHP_EOL;
        $unixTime = strtotime("+1 day", $unixTime);
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
01 Jan 2004
02 Jan 2004
03 Jan 2004
...
29 Dec 2012
30 Dec 2012
31 Dec 2012
```

This also has the added bonus of not showing "31 Feb 2008" etc., as that date doesn't even exist.

[Codepad example of the code (WARNING: long output!)](http://codepad.org/EvODIXwP)

**Edit**

If you want to replace every date like this with a space, you can use this one-liner (replace every date with a space):

```
$result = preg_replace("/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{4}/", " ", $result);
```

It will turn

> 01 Jan 2004 blah blah 02 Jan 2004 and blah 03 Jan 2004 and who even cares about 31 Dec 2050? I know that I don't.

into

> blah blah   and blah   and who even cares about  ? I know that I don't.

Comment: but if you have a look again in the code, i need to use `str_replace` for every date to replace those date by a space. I will use this in simple html php dom parser

Comment: @MaxMuller Then instead of `echo date("d M Y", $unixTime) . PHP_EOL;` use `$result = str_replace(date("d M Y", $unixTime), " ", $result);`.

Comment: @MaxMuller Optionally, check my edit. It might be way more of what you need.

Comment: one more question, is this will also check `1 Jan 2004` not `01 Jan 2004` etc ... ?

Comment: @MaxMuller No - it won't, but then you can change the first part of the regex to this: `([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])` instead of `([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])`.

Comment: @h200000 may you have the time to show an example in http://codepad.org with `$result = preg_replace("/([1-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]{4}/", " ", $result);` Thanks

Comment: one more issue : i am using this code in a Simple PHP HTML DOM Parse (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but i cant understand why its not working .. do u have any idea?

Comment: @MaxMuller It depends on your current code. My suggestion is that you create a new thread with your new code.